# Custom SimpleCursorAdapter - overloaded bindView issue with onClickListener

Tags: java, android, android-cursoradapter

I have created a custom SimpleCursorAdapter in which i have overridden `bindView` so I can connect an `onClick` listener of an ImageButton in the list item layout. I want to start a new application on when the button is clicked using an `Intent` with some extra data set from the underlying `Cursor`.

The problem is that when the `onClick` function of the button gets called, the cursor seems to no longer be pointing at the correct row in the database (I assume this is because it has been changed to point at a different row as the list scrolls).

Here is my code:

```
private class WaveFxCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

public WaveFxCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
    String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c) {
    super.bindView(v, context, c);
    ImageButton b = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_show_spec);

    // fchr is correct here:
    int fchr = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(
                 WaveDataContentProvider.SiteForecast.FORECAST_PERIOD));

    Log.d(TAG, "ChrisB: bindView: FCHR is: " + fchr );

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), SpecDrawActivity.class);
            i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.putExtra("com.kernowsoft.specdraw.SITENAME", mSitename);

            // fchr is NOT CORRECT here! I can't use the fchr from the
            // bindView method as Lint tells me this is an error:
            int fchr = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(
                 WaveDataContentProvider.SiteForecast.FORECAST_PERIOD));

            Log.d(TAG, "bindView: Forecast hour is: " + fchr);
            i.putExtra("com.kernowsoft.specdraw.FCHR", fchr);
            getActivity().startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see from the comments in the code above, `fchr` is correct when I print it to the log in `bindView` but it is incorrect in the `onClick` method. I tried referencing the `fchr` variable in `bindView` from the `onClick` method, but Andriod Lint tells me i cant do this:

> Cannot refer to a non-final variable fchr inside an inner class defined in a different method

My Question is: How can I correctly pass the `fchr` variable from the cursor into the `onClick` method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the error is variable `fchr` is a local variable in the bindView() method. The object that you create with the anonymous class might last until after the bindView() method returns.

When the bindView() method returns, local variables will be cleaned up from the stack, so they won't exist anymore after bindView() returns.

But the anonymous class object reference the variable `fchr`. Things would go horribly wrong if the anonymous class object tries to access a variable after it have been cleaned up.

By making `fchr` final, they are not really variables anymore, but constants. The compiler can then just replace the use of `fchr` in the anonymous class with the values of the constants, and you won't have the problem with accessing non-existent variables anymore.

See [Working with inner classes](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/java-inner-classes_android/)

Comment: If I declare the variable in the class, I still get the same Lint error. Are then any repercussions of making the  variable final?

Comment: Sorry - my first comment was incorrect. Declaring the variable in the class does NOT produce a lint error, but it still returns the wrong fchr. Making the variable final works, but is this the recommended way to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: yup. It is the recommend way thats why the lint error shows **Cannot refer to a non-final variable**

Answer (score 0):

instead of:

```
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
```

use:

```
b.setOnClickListener(new MyClickListener(fchr));
```

and the class MyClickListener would look like:

```
class MyClickListener implements OnClickListener {
    int mFchr;
    public MyClickListener(int fchr) {
        mFchr = fchr;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // here you can access mFchr
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah- that doesn't work because OnClickListener is an interface and it does not have a constructor.